# How should onClick Listener by defined and instantiated for an Activity

Tags: android

My Activity has multiple lists so I have defined MyClickListener as below:

My question is how I should instantiate this class:

```
 MyClickListener mMyClickListener = new MyClickListener();
```

Or maybe it is better to instantiate inside the onCreate(Bundle) and just define above.  Whats considered the better way?  I don't want too much in onCreate() its already full of stuff. Any thoughts on the declaration and instatiation?  Whats the best way?

```
private class MyClickListener implements OnClickListener
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }

}
```

Comment: if your activity having multiple list then how can you work with OnClikcListener. You should go with OnItemClickedListener

Comment: No @nick because these clicks occur in items inside the footer and header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use same kind of class mechanism as you mentioned in the question.

this is the way i use,

```
public class myActivity extends Activity
{
    private MyListener listener = null;

    private Button cmdButton = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

                cmdButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmdButton);
                cmdButton.setOnClickListener(getListener());

    }


    // method to fetch the listener object
    private MyListener getListener() 
    {
        if (listener == null) 
        {
            listener = new MyListener();
        }
        return listener;
    }

       private class MyListener implements Button.OnClickListener 
       {
             public void onClick(View v) 
             {
             }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you instantiating a listener like that in the first place?  Just create a new one when you assign it to your listView.

```
listView.setOnClickListener( new MyListener());
```